# Insert HTML using jQuery at cursors last position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a forum which is generated by my CMS. I have no control over this code. Within this code I need to insert HTML. I have read other post similar to this one but those all involve using `<textarea>` on forms. My code is a bit different.

Here is the generated code:

```
<iframe id="re_contentIframe">
 <html>
  <body>

  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

As a person types it automatically inserts the code into the `<body>` tag. 
IE:

```
<iframe id="re_contentIframe">
 <html>
  <body>
   <p>As a person types it adds the <p> tags.</p>
  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

I have a function that inserts HTML dynamically when a person performs an action such as uploading a file. Currently that function appends the dynamic content before the closing `<body>` tag. What I want it to do is insert the HTML where the cursor last was within the the iFrame's body tag.

Here is a visual example:

```
<iframe id="re_contentIframe">
 <html>
  <body>
   <p>Forum content is typed here.</p>
   <p>Content.</p>
   <p>Content.</p>
   <p><!-- Last place the cursor was located is here! --></p>
   <p>More forum content.</p>
  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

In looking at the above code I want the HTML inserted exactly at the location the cursor was. In this example it was the second to last `<p>` tag BUT this won't always be the same exact place.

Is it possible to do this and how?

In other words:

```
[Find Cursor Position] function() {
  //My code to insert HTML
});
```

***EDIT***

My CMS generates the code for the forum post. When rendered it appears as this:

[image: Screenshot]

The part that has my name in it is the area I can edit and type in. The area I can type is generated by my CMS and looks like this:

```
<iframe id="re_contentIframe">
 <html>
  <body>
   Lynda =>
  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

As I type the HTML changes to this:

```
<iframe id="re_contentIframe">
 <html>
  <body>
   <p>What I type is wrapped in <p> tags by the forum code.</p>
   <p>New Paragraph and so on...</p>
   Lynda =>
  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

What I need to do is at the very last place the cursor was located in the body of this iFrame I need to insert code upon an action that is triggered by a JS function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bbE48/13/ Check this fiddle

Comment: @dholakiyaankit - I saw that but what is confusing me is that uses a `textarea` and I am not.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `contenteditable`? By "cursor" I assume you mean "mouse cursor" (since there is generally no text insertion caret for non-editable regions), is that correct? It seems like a strange behavior.

Comment: @DaggNabbit - Yes I mean mouse cursor. I don't control the code my CMS uses and I assume I cannot use `contenteditable`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "don't control the code." You must have some control over some of the code or this question would be pointless, right? Can you clarify what exactly you do and do not have control over?

Comment: Also, if you're saying the CMS actually *doesn't use a text cursor* and stuff just appears out of nowhere as you type, that sounds very strange; I'd think about looking at other CMS options (maybe some open-source CMS, so you can have control over the code). If it does have a text cursor, I'd think that would be the place to insert text, not the location of the mouse cursor.

Comment: @DaggNabbit - I don't believe I am explaining it well. Look at my edit to my question please. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Could you use a setTimeout with something like this: `$('*').hover(function() {hoverElem = this});`

Comment: @JeffS - Not sure that would work.

Comment: @Lynda, maybe I'm just being particularly dense tonight but it still doesn't make much sense to me. If you *did* have control over the code and you *were* looking to insert content at the text cursor, I'd say that editor looks like one of the prepackaged wysiwyg deals... tinymce, ckeditor, nicedit, something like that. I'd find out which one, and look at its API, and see if it provides an easy way to do what you want. If it doesn't, start looking into `Range` and `Selection`.

Comment: @DaggNabbit - It is okay, I am unsure how to better explain it. I believe it is one and I will see what I can find. When I say I don't have control of the code I mean I can add code using javascript but I can't go in and add a class to the iFrame or code within, it all much be done with javascript. Thank you for your help.